# Simple inequality with exponential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I have bounded $A$ by
$$
e^{-\epsilon c}(\cosh c)^n
$$
for any $c>0$, and if I'm correct the minimum occurs when
$\tanh c=\epsilon/n$. By the right choice of $c$, I want to show that
$$
A\le e^{-\epsilon c}(\cosh c)^n\le e^{-{\epsilon}^2/2n}.
$$
Could someone please help me see if a $c>0$ exists such that the above inequality holds?

Answer (score 1):

If the inequality were true, taking the limit as $c\to0^+$ we would have
$$
1\le e^{-\epsilon^2/(2n)}.
$$
The right hand side is $<1$, so that the inequality does not hold for all $c>0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to bound $A$, so I just need to see if there exists a $c$ such that the inequalitly holds.